# Open newest file from wildcards vba

Tags: excel, vba

Good day,

I am trying to open an archived workbook in the "Archive" folder to copy contents of a worksheet to a new workbook with the same sheet name.
There are multiple files in folder and the opened file depends on the customer name. (there will be multiple customers and multiple workbooks with a single customer)

The file names are all structured as PREFIX (FSO or PPG), Ticket Number (111234), Customer Name, Job Type and Short Date, like, "FSO 111234 Co Name Job Type 022822.xlsm"

My issue is that the following code opens the first file in the folder and not the newest file. I require the newest file from the wild carded customer name.

```
Public Sub Archive_Ticket_Fill()
    
Dim xpath, xfile, LatestFile As String
Dim InternalWB, wb As Workbook
Dim LatestDate, LMD As Date

Set wb = Nothing
xpath = "C:\Start\Archive\"
If Right(xpath, 1) <> "\" Then xpath = xpath & "\"
xfile = Dir$(xpath & "*" & Worksheets("DM").Range("D10").Value & "*.xlsm", vbNormal)

If Len(xfile) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do While Len(xfile) > 0
    LMD = FileDateTime(xpath & xfile)
    If LMD >= LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = xfile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    xfile = Dir
Loop

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks(LatestFile)
On Error GoTo 0

If wb Is Nothing Then
    Set InternalWB = Workbooks.Open(xpath & LatestFile)
    'COPY CODE HERE
    Else
    MsgBox LatestFile & " is already open."
    'COPY CODE HERE
End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe the create/modify dates on your files dont match the date in the filename?

Comment: This code behaves exactly as expected here, *if I strip out the D10 reference*. I can only assume that the data you have in D10 is restricting the list of files the routine is checking against. I'd suggest adding a `Debug.Print xfile` line after your `If Len(xfile)=0` line that outputs the file being examined so you can see which files are matching your ...*.xlsm pattern.

Comment: I am dumb. This code did work the entire time. It was bringing up an older ticket number because it was the most recently edited workbook. Thank you for your help.